# Jenkins Dockerfile works but not in docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Running Jenkins from docker-compose via this (simplified) docker-compose.yml on a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  jenkins:
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    image: mpcjenkins
    build: 
      context: ./master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io` and especially cannot send email (testing gives `java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp...`), although it works when I run it directly via `docker run -p "8080:8080" -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home mpcjenkins`. Strangely it also works via docker-compose on my local Mac. I need docker-compose for some stuff I left out of the simplified version.

I tried privileged, cleared the volume, disabled ufw, used the ip address of the smtp server, changed ssl/tls settings - nothing helped.

Shortened version of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home

ARG JAVA_OPTS
ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true ${JAVA_OPTS:-}"
USER root

COPY plugins_extra.txt $JENKINS_HOME/plugins_extra.txt
COPY groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d

RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < $JENKINS_HOME/plugins_extra.txt && \
    apt-get ...... && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins && \
    chown -R jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME/ 
USER jenkins
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the shared `volumes` section from the bottom and only reference within the service?

Comment: That gives me `Named volume "jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:rw" is used in service "jenkins" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.` Do I have to change the volume declaration inside the service also?

Comment: You aren't providing the cli command with a context. Why?

Comment: @Gerriet It will create a directory called `/jenkins_home/` in the root of the file system if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please provide information about the operating system this runs on? I use MacOS and I know it has issues with volume mounts especially if it outside of the directory that contains the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I have the problems on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. On MacOS it works.

Comment: @Tom I use the directory `./master` as a build context for `docker image build` and `docker-compose build` , not for running the container (`docker run` or `docker-compose up`). Am I missing something there?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Using a local directory as a volume (and removing it from the volume list in docker-compose) makes no difference.